# dynamic image in rdlc not appear correctly

Tags: c#, rdlc

I have this hirarcy in my project

Report forlder -> Image Folder , Reports -> Rdlc

in rdlc I set the image source to external and use parameter

when add the parameter to report call the report not appear

I write the parameter like

"file:images\icon.jpg" is there an certain extension to use or why this cause the report to not appear ,I tried to remove the image and the report work fine

Comment: did you gave a look to this blog entry? http://satishjdotnet.blogspot.ch/2009/03/external-images-in-rdlc-reports-aspnet.html

Comment: still cannot see ther report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should pass the complete image path to your image in this way if you pass it like you've done I don't thik it will work.

```
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter("image", "file:///" + Server.MapPath("~/images/icon.jpg",true));
```